# Python treating digit and float as same index in list

Tags: python-3.x, list, indexing

I am trying to find index value of list from below code.

```
a = [4.5, 6 , "hi" , 6.0]
for b in a:
    if type(b)==float:
        print(a.index(float(b))+0, b , id(b))
    else:
        print(a.index(b)+0 , b , id(b))
```

what I found is for value "6" and "6.0" is taking same  index position from the output.
How do I get different index value for each value in list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list.index function is not written to discriminate between types. If you want this, you'll have to write your own function. Using enumeration in your loop will give the real index.

```
a = [4.5, 6 , "hi" , 6.0]
for idx, b in enumerate(a):
    if type(b)==float:
        print(idx, b , id(b))
    else:
        print(idx , b , id(b))
```

You can wrap this code in a function to create a new type-sensitive index function which only returns `idx`.